# Output signature of openssl_sign to screen to copy/paste for C/C++ usage?

Tags: php

I am playing around with signature verification using PHP on Linux and C++ on Windows.   I have this test php script working to create the signature ($privatekey is defined, no point in providing it) but I want to output in a format I can just copy / paste over to the test program on the Windows side.  But the output is just one item (not each individual byte).   How can I fix the below to output the individual bytes like 0x01, 0x02, 0x33, etc.. instead of 0x010233 etc.. ?

```
<?php

$datatohash="test123";

$hashvalue=hash("sha256", $datatohash);

if (openssl_sign($hashvalue, $signature, $privatekey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)) {
    echo "Success: ", $hashvalue, "\n", base64_encode($signature), "\n\n";

    echo "BYTE signature[]={ ";
    $arr = unpack("H*",$signature);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "0x$value, ";
    }
    echo "};\n";
}
else {
    echo "Failure:";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the output loop to process each character in the string works:

```
<?php

$datatohash="test123";

$hashvalue=hash("sha256", $datatohash);

if (openssl_sign($hashvalue, $signature, $privatekey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)) {
    echo "Success: ", $hashvalue, "\n", base64_encode($signature), "\n\n";

    echo "BYTE signature[]={ ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($signature); $i++) {
        echo "0x", dechex(ord($signature[$i])), ",";
    }       
    echo "};\n";
}
else {
    echo "Failure:";
}
?>
```